# Getting undefined on Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Simple:getSelectionsCollection() from bundle product

Tags: magento-1.9, bundle

We are migrating away from magento 1.9 and as one of the last steps we need to extract bundles data.
As an easy approach I found this solution:

```
$product_id = "TestBundle";
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
$selctionCollection = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection(
    $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($product), $product
);
foreach($selctionCollection as $option) {
    print_r($option);
}
```

But strangely I get a fatal error `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Simple::getSelectionsCollection()`, which assumes the loaded product is a simple product. But it isn't, definitely! I created it newly as a bundle product and get the same behavior with other existing bundle products, too. As far as I know it should be `Mage_Bundle`.

Did anybody overcome this error or have any idea how to work around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error came from a wrong value in `$product_id`. Don't know why, but I put the SKU in there, while the product ID was needed.

Without getting any error I did not suspect this to be a problem. When using a product ID, it works as expected.